# php set_exception_handler() not catching exceptions

Tags: php, exception

As far as I know, the exception handler should handle any exceptions in any part of my script (classes, functions, etc.).

My exception handler doesn't catch any exceptions although, I tried many times and versions. Can someone help me find the problem? I use nginx & php-fpm (latest).

```
<?php
    require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';
    set_exception_handler(['\App\Core\ExceptionHandler','handler']);
```

The exception handler -

```
namespace App\Core;


class ExceptionHandler
{
    public static function handler(\Throwable $e)
    {
        .....
    }
}
```

Comment: [Please read how to create a minimal, complete, and verifiable example.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)  Without an example of code, it's impossible to know what is wrong for us to be able to help.

Comment: I will add a code example but, I don't think it will help. I tried many times and many different ways.

Comment: The exception execute after you set your exception handler with `set_exception_handler` right ?

Comment: Yes, of course. one of my controllers/models will raise the exception.

Comment: So, I guess no one knows how to solve it? Can anyone try to implement it on his own server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve the problem by using proxy class.

So, all of my calls to the controllers wrapped by a main controller class with try-catch block.

So, when our script throws exception, we can send it to our exception handler.

I think it's a better solution after all.